# I' Am getting appRecognitionVerdict as UNRECOGNIZED_VERSION in play Integrity Standard API Request for normal device

Tags: android, kotlin, google-api-client, google-play-integrity-api

Currently getting this response from the API.

{"tokenPayloadExternal":{"accountDetails":{"appLicensingVerdict":"LICENSED"},"appIntegrity":{"appRecognitionVerdict":"UNRECOGNIZED_VERSION","certificateSha256Digest":["KDSOFDOFJDOGKCasfjidofmo"],"packageName":"packagename","versionCode":"1"},"deviceIntegrity":{"deviceRecognitionVerdict":["MEETS_DEVICE_INTEGRITY"]},"requestDetails":{"requestHash":"dsjandfkhsufcjnioxdcjsdASFSDGISPFkaiofjodkfolkfovfgvd=\n","requestPackageName":"packagename","timestampMillis":"123659412774525"}}}

I have referred https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdicts this documentation but didn't find any solution to resolved UNRECOGNIZED_VERSION error in normal device.

Can someone provide insights or solutions on how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your app needs to be published first so that the app version is registered in Google Play, otherwise from the point of view of the Integrity API the request is coming from an unknown app version. The app doesn't need to be publically available for this to work, you can publish to a Closed Testing track for example.